# Can't use Browse button Quick upload product

Tags: image, file-upload, file, plone

I have installed the Quick Upload product in Plone 4.0 to upload lots of photo's.
In a new & empty testsite the Portlet can be activated and "Choose your files" is visible with and a dark red Browse button. Uploading works just fine.

In a current Plonesite with a lot of content I also want to add the Quick Upload add on product. I can define the portlet in the Plone-site but there is no browse  button visible.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have not read the instructions which imply that the latest version (1.1.0) is compatible with plone 4 only. If this is the case pin collective.quickupload to 1.0.3 by adding in your buildout:

```
[versions]
collective.quickupload = 1.0.3
```